# Wrong colors when rendering SKTexture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm have an SKTexture generated by a GKNoiseMap. When I look at the texture in a swift playground, it has the expected colours. When I apply the texture to a material and render it in a SCNView, the colours are different (see images below). What am I doing wrong?

[image: SKTexture in Playground]
[image: Rendered image]

Full code:

```
import GameKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let source = GKPerlinNoiseSource()
let noise = GKNoise(source)
noise.gradientColors = [-1: #colorLiteral(red: 0.7537418008, green: 0.4404714704, blue: 0.2776784003, alpha: 1) , 1: #colorLiteral(red: 0.2008953691, green: 0.186568588, blue: 0.2595013976, alpha: 1)]
let map = GKNoiseMap(noise, size: vector2(1.0, 1.0), origin: vector2(0.0, 0.0), sampleCount: vector2(Int32(256), Int32(256)), seamless: false)
let texture = SKTexture(noiseMap: map )


let ball = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
let materials = SCNMaterial()
materials.diffuse.contents = texture
ball.materials = [materials]
var node = SCNNode(geometry: ball)


var sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView

var cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 3)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why this works (I suspect this has something to do with gamma correction), but here is a workaround:

Convert the SKTexture to an UIImage, then assign the UIimage to the material's diffuse contents. This shows correct colours.